# SQLite3 stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, rubygems

I have been working on an ruby app for a while, and today starting up my server via "rails server" I now get this:

```
/Users/Ross/rails_projects/splash/json/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

What I changed before this, was I installed the curb and json gems.  The funny thing is it still works on Heroku, just not my local machine.  So it must be environmental.  However, I cannot figure out what broke and why.

Still stuck, noticed if I load up irb:

```
    MacBook-Pro:splash Ross$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > require 'sqlite3'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 >
```

So why does that work and not the rails server?  I even tried to reinstall rails.  Nothing.  Path issue?

Update: Still not working, tried another of solutions: building from source, uninstall, reinstall, upgrade rails, etc.  The message has changed slightly:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Ross/rails_projects/splash/json/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

I really need help, this is really killing my productivity.

Comment: Open this file. Show us the 239th line and we will know.

Comment: Have you updated anything lately?

Comment: Yeah, I installed the curb and json gems...

Comment: Did you do a gem list (or bundle list if you are using bundler)? Is the gem you expect to be there actually ... there?

Comment: Yes they are all there:
  * actionmailer (3.0.3)
  * actionpack (3.0.3)
  * activemodel (3.0.3)
  * activerecord (3.0.3)
  * activeresource (3.0.3)
  * activesupport (3.0.3)
  * arel (2.0.8)
  * bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
  * builder (2.1.2)
  * bundler (1.0.11)
  * curb (0.7.15)
  * devise (1.1.7)
  * erubis (2.6.6)
  * i18n (0.5.0)
  * json (1.5.1)
  * mail (2.2.15)
  * mime-types (1.16)
  * polyglot (0.3.1)
  * rack (1.2.1)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.3)
  * sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * treetop (1.4.9)
  * tzinfo (0.3.24)
  * warden (1.0.3)

Comment: Interesting enough if I do irb and load sqlite3, it works... so what is different in starting the server?  ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > require 'sqlite3'
dyld: loaded: /Volumes/SSD/Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
dyld: loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, install homebrew and rvm as per [my blog post here](http://blog.bsodmike.com/2011/04/19/rvm-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/).

```
$ rvm --default 1.9.2
```

It'll spit out a comment giving you the install command to grab the latest ruby.  Then repeat the above command to set it.  You can test this by doing

```
$ ruby -v
```

It should show you something similar to the following, although I'm using 1.8.7

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10.2.0]
```

Now simply reinstall rails `gem install rails` and do `bundle install`.  By using rvm, and hopefully a newer version of ruby, it'll setup a whole new space for you to test out a new deploy.  Hopefully you won't get the same issue again.  Keep us posted :)

Comment: @RossR I think when you perform require in irb, it's accessing the gems stored in `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/`, for example I have `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.2.4/lib/sqlite3` although this is not what I'm access now since I'm using rvm.

Comment: This is where rvm stores my gems for dev `/Users/mdesilva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Mike.  Funny thing was it didn't work.  After I did it, I got a message about curl was missing.  So I installed it and the sqlite3 error popped up immediately again.

A ton more Googling and I found an post about installing sqlite3 through RVM.
so I did a:

```
rvm gem install sqlite3
```

then I did:

```
rm -rf .bundle && bundle install
```

Then it started working.  I'm not sure if it was the deleting the bundle or installing through rvm, but either way it's working again.